# Powershell Read a text file and extract 2 values ComputerName & ProductName

Tags: powershell, file, text, extract

I read text file which contains a lot of information.
I need to extract only 2 values: 1- ComputerName & ProductName.
I have written the below script and the end result is 2 headers and the rest is blank.

```
SystemName=ABC123 (This is the ComputerName)
ProductName=USB Audio Device



$FileName0 = "C:\DATA\AUDIT\DRAGON\DRAGON.TXT"
foreach ($computer in (Get-Content C:\DATA\AUDIT\DRAGON\COMPUTERS11.TXT)) {
wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like 'USB%'" get /value  | Out-File "C:\DATA\AUDIT\DRAGON\DRAGON.TXT"}
Get-content $FileName0 | Select-Object $computer, ProductName | Out-File C:\DATA\AUDIT\DRAGON\DRAGON-USB.TXT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read in your computer list
2. Run the script on each computer using Get-WmiObject
3. Compile the data you want.

```
$hash = @{}

foreach($server in Get-Content computers.txt) {
    $result = (Get-WmiObject CIM_LogicalDevice -Filter "Description like 'USB%'" -ComputerName $server | select Name).Name
    $hash[$server] = $result
}

# At this point, your hashtable has a list of all servers with all the products that have description starting with USB.

#Convert to Json and save it to file.
$hash | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File test.txt

# And to convert it to csv, use the following with GetEnumerator.
$hash.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object -Property @{N='Property';E={$_.Key}}, @{N='PropValue';E={$_.Value -Join "|"}}  | Export-Csv test.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I export the result of this script in a file e.g. toto.txt? I tried but the result is looping. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user270488 see updated post to include how to export it (json / csv)

Comment: Hi,

The result is like below BUT with hundreds of values between "|".
"SERVER1"  "USB Audio Device|USB Audio Device|A|B|C|...|PowerMicII-NS|"

I need to have the result like below:
"SERVER1"  "PowerMicII-NS"
If the server does NOT have the value "PowerMicII-NS", I do not need the server in the result file
Sorry for asking but I can not find a way to obtain the final result because the value are so numerous and varied.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user270488 your original post was asking for all usb devices and only way I could think of producing a csv of an array was to use a different delimiter.  If you are looking for a specific device, change the filter where you are looking up a description. `-Filter "Description LIKE 'PowerMicII'"`

Comment: I tried this -Filter "Description LIKE 'PowerMicII'" but the "PropValue" is now empty for the entire file . Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you confirm if there is a computer with that logical device attached? Run just the `get-wmiobject CIM_LogicalDevice` to see what the name / description of that device is supposed to be and use that in the filter.

Comment: Yes, there is a microphone connected to my computer.
I run the command and the microphone is (Generic USB Audio) <>  PowerMicII-NS. 
2 instances of (Generic USB Audio).
How can  I filter for (Generic USB Audio)? Thanks.

Comment: Then look at the name and description... you might be better off using the name instead of the description in the filter